# How to close partial view after save/edit?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, crud

I have a CRUD table and I managed to create/edit/delete it with updating the only partial view. But I have a problem after one of operation with create/edit. After pressed submit button my partial view doesn't close.

Guys, please help or give me tips ;) I'll be really very thankful.

Here the example for creating.

Conroller:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult ViewCreate()
{
  return PartialView("_Create");
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(Menu cust)
{                   
   int create_file_id = cust.File_Id;
   sMenuRepository.Add(cust);           
   return RedirectToAction("ViewTable", create_file_id);
}
```

View:

```html
<div class="modal-body">
  <h2>Create</h2>
  <form
    asp-controller="Home"
    asp-action="Create"
    data-ajax="true"
    data-ajax-update="#divPartial"
  >
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button
        id="myHide"
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-default"
        data-dismiss="modal"
      >
        Cancel
      </button>
      <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#approve-btn').click(function () {
                alert('Hi');
                $('#modal-container').modal('hide');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow :) Ok so, `$('#modal-container').modal('hide');`, where is the attribute `id="modal-container"` defined? Should it not be `$(".model-body")`?

Comment: with modal-body the same ;(

Comment: What does your console say?

Comment: Please show more markups such as `approve-btn`

Comment: Thank you all a lot! I fixed my problem! It was a conflict between js scripts.